# ajax post request to spring controller

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, jsp

I am trying to send form data as a JSON from my jsp file to a spring controller.
For this, I am using jquery ajax post method to hit the controller.
I am able to touch the controller and get the JSON. In both places, i.e on ajax method call and controller, I am using POST request. But still, the data gets displayed on url. Below are my files.

JSP page code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#submitButton").click(function(){
         var formData=getFormData();
         var strUrl="http://localhost:8080/Test_ReportingUI/addDb.htm";
         $.post(strUrl, {jsonData: JSON.stringify(formData)},
                  function(response){
                    if(response.status=='ok') {
                      alert("ok");
                    } else {
                      alert('not OK');
                    }
                  }, 'json');
        });
});
```

Spring controller:

```
  @RequestMapping (value="addDb.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  ModelAndView  addEditCustomer()
   {
      ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("custDB_setup");
      System.out.println("Hello World..");

 return modelAndView;
}
```

[image]

I want to know why am I getting parameters in above shown URL image.

Answer (score 1):

Making an assumption based on the name of the `submitButton` element and the behaviour you're seeing, it sounds like you need to instead hook an event to the `submit` event of the `form` element instead of the button so that you can cancel the standard form submission which is occurring as well as your AJAX request. Try this:

```
 $("form").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var formData = getFormData();
     $.post('http://localhost:8080/Test_ReportingUI/addDb.htm', {
         jsonData: JSON.stringify(formData)
     }, function(response){
           if (response.status == 'ok') {
                alert("ok");
            } else {
                alert('not OK');
           }
      }, 'json');
 });
```

The `form` selector is an example, you should change that to be relevant to your HTML. Note that it would be better practice to provide `FormData` or a plain object to the `data` parameter instead of hacking around whatever data you're providing to `JSON.stringify` manually. This is because jQuery will automatically encode values for you where needed. Also, given your example, `response.status` should really be a boolean. Something like this:

```
 $("form").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var formData = new FormData(this);
     $.post('http://localhost:8080/Test_ReportingUI/addDb.htm', formData, function(response){
           if (response.status) {
                alert("ok");
            } else {
                alert('not OK');
           }
      }, 'json');
 });
```

Comment: by using the above mentioned code by you, parameter in URL are now not visible. That is what I wanted. But on submit of form to controller, the matter in the text fields does not vanishes. Text fields does not blank on submission of form.

Comment: You need to clear them yourself, `$('input').val('')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(e){
  var formData=getFormData();
  var strUrl="http://localhost:8080/Test_ReportingUI/addDb.htm";
  $.post(strUrl, {jsonData: JSON.stringify(formData)},function(response){
    if(response.status=='ok') {
      alert("ok");
    } else {
      alert('not OK');
    }
  }, 'json');
  e.preventDefault(); // Use jquery style to cancel default click action of element
  return false; // Or use this line to completely cancel default action
});
```

I have commented last two lines of your needed code lines just use one of them. The problem is your submit buttons default behaviour. So you want to make an ajax call for your form. But your submit button also works its default action. To avoid them you need to use `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();` to exceed that problem. In your code also runs javascript but the default action is more faster than async js job(ajax). So page changes immediately and you couldn't see your ajax result.

Comment: By using your code, the parameters in URL are resolved, i.e. they are now not showing in url. But after I submit the form the data gets there in the fields. Data entered does not become blank on submit of form.

Comment: @JSK So, you should clear your input values to get blank form inputs. `$("form").reset();` or clear specific input fields via `$("input").val("");`